# HTTP ERROR 500 Laravel on Digitalocean

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean

I installed Laravel on Digitalocean vps (Ubuntu 16.04), but I have the following error, I have already given write permissions to storage.

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89KZI.jpg)

Comment: Can you tell us what version of PHP you're using on the webserver? You've got a different version of Symfony's `Response.php` than I do (I don't have a `?` on line 491 of mine), but I suspect it's code like `public function getCharset(): ?string` that's tripping up an older version of PHP.

Comment: That's right, I was using php 7.1.17 but I needed a higher version than php 7.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using php 7.1.17 but I needed a higher version than php 7.1.3

Laravel 5.6 requirements:

- PHP >= 7.1.3
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- ...